# NSUserDefaults causing performance issues

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I believe I have CPU performance issues caused by overuse of NSUserDefaults. Is this possible?

I am debugging some code that has used it to store a lot of user data and now subsequent calls to store data are talking over 4 seconds per call.

What would be causing these long delays?

```
// Save data in user defaults
NSDate *timerStartTime = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"Data Size %lu", (unsigned long)[result.data length]);
[self setObject:result.data forKey:defaultName];
NSTimeInterval elapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:timerStartTime];
NSLog(@"Time For Function: %f", elapsed);
```

Output:

> Time For Function: 4.1

Comment: okay, and what is your _data size_? you have gracefully bypassed to share that info...

Comment: are you using iOS8 or iOS7? in iOS 8 works much faster

Comment: using IOS7, and data size is hard to tell because its storing an array of dictionaries with text in them so not sure how to get the size of all that. there are 17 arrays each with varying sizes, some up to 300 items in them

Comment: changing to IOS8 does not solve the problem

Comment: You can find the file on your Mac and check its size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are storing large amounts of data you should definitely not use NSUserDefaults to do so.

NSUserDefaults is good to use for things such as flags, simple settings or user variables such as a nickname, etc. Essentially user preferences.

This is because:

- NSUserDefaults is loaded and saved in its entirety every time it is loaded.
- NSUserDefaults is loaded on the application launch so you cannot
  thread its loading process.

Storing data should be done using Core Data:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Or if it is simply a Dictionary or Array of strings you can use Property Lists:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

NSUserDefaults does use a pList to store its data so you will come across some of the same limitations but you will have more control as to when and how you will write or read your data. Also, it is not good practice to use NSUserDefaults as a make-shift DB when it has an intended purpose of preferences.

Comment: I agree I was just wondering the reasons behind it, is NSuserDefaults backed up by MySQL or is it just saving to a file.. which if so would probably mean copying a lot of data around and would make sense from a performance penalty point of view

Comment: NSUserDefaults is basically a NSDictionary. The data that is stored in NSUserDefaults is saved in one plist per app (and domain?!). It gets slow if you use huge amounts of data because the whole structure has to be saved every time.

Comment: Matthias Bauch is correct, I have updated my answer with more information as well.

Comment: I suspected this might be the case.. super thanks guys.